# Lazy CosmosDB Initialization takes longer when more tasks are waiting for it

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

**Context**

We have a service that is dependent on CosmosDB. We created a class, having a lazy container, that will be initialized on startup. In the startup class we do :

- CreateDatabaseIfNotExist
- CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync

**Problem**
The first request to CosmosDB starts the initialization.
When we have multiple threads starting up before the initialization, waiting for this lazy intialization to finish, the intialization takes longer the more threads are waiting for it.

**Expected**
When multiple threads starting up, the threads that need to have this initialized container, should not impact the initialization duration, since this is in a locked context (lazy)

In the code example below, when changing the amount of threads to 5, the initialization is in a couple of seconds. the higher the count of threads, the higher the duration of the initialization.

code example:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;

namespace LazyCosmos.Anon
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Do().Run().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        public class Do
        {
            private Lazy<Container> lazyContainer;
            private Container Container => lazyContainer.Value;

            public Do()
            {
                lazyContainer = new Lazy<Container>(() => InitializeContainer().GetAwaiter().GetResult());
            }

            public async Task Run()
            {
                try
                {
                    var tasks = new Task[100];
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        tasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
                            ReadItemAsync<Item>("XXX", "XXX"));
                    }
                    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw;
                }

            }

            public async Task<T> ReadItemAsync<T>(string id, string partitionKey)
            {
                var itemResponse = await Container.ReadItemAsync<T>(id, new PartitionKey(partitionKey));

                return itemResponse.Resource;
            }

            private async Task<Container> InitializeContainer()
            {
                var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                Console.WriteLine($"Started {s.ElapsedMilliseconds}s");
                var configuration = new CosmosDbServiceConfiguration("XXX", null, collectionId: "XXX",
                    "XXX", 400);

                var _cosmosClient = new ColdStorageCosmosClient(new ActorColdStorageConfiguration("XXX", "XXX", "https://XXX.XX", "XXX"));

                var database = await _cosmosClient
                    .CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(configuration.DatabaseId, configuration.DatabaseThroughput);
                Console.WriteLine($"CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync took {s.ElapsedMilliseconds}s");

                var containerProperties = new ContainerProperties
                {
                    Id = configuration.ContainerId,
                    PartitionKeyPath = $"/{configuration.PartitionKey}",
                    DefaultTimeToLive = configuration.DefaultTimeToLive
                };

                var db = (Database)database;
                var containerIfNotExistsAsync = await db.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerProperties, configuration.ContainerThroughput);

                s.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync took {s.ElapsedMilliseconds}s");

                return containerIfNotExistsAsync;
            }
        }
    }

    public class CosmosDbServiceConfiguration
    {
        public CosmosDbServiceConfiguration(string databaseId, int? databaseThroughput, string collectionId, string partitionKey, int? containerThroughput = null)
        {

            DatabaseId = databaseId;
            ContainerId = collectionId;
            DatabaseThroughput = databaseThroughput;
            ContainerThroughput = containerThroughput;
            PartitionKey = partitionKey;
        }
        public string DatabaseId { get; }
        public int? DatabaseThroughput { get; }
        public string ContainerId { get; }
        public int? ContainerThroughput { get; }
        public string PartitionKey { get; }
        public int? DefaultTimeToLive { get; set; }
    }

    public class ColdStorageCosmosClient : CosmosClient
    {
        public ColdStorageCosmosClient(ActorColdStorageConfiguration actorColdStorageConfiguration) : base(actorColdStorageConfiguration.EndpointUrl, actorColdStorageConfiguration.Key)
        {

        }
    }

    public class ActorColdStorageConfiguration
    {
        public ActorColdStorageConfiguration(string databaseName, string collectionName, string endpointUrl, string key)
        {
            DatabaseName = databaseName;
            CollectionName = collectionName;
            EndpointUrl = endpointUrl;
            Key = key;
        }

        public string DatabaseName { get; }

        public string CollectionName { get; }

        public string EndpointUrl { get; }

        public string Key { get; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string id { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this running? ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're experiencing thread pool exhaustion. There's a few different concepts that are conflicting to cause the exhaustion.

First, [even though asynchronous code does not use a thread for the duration of the asynchronous operation, it often *does* need to very briefly borrow a thread pool thread in order to do housework when the asynchronous operation completes](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). As a result, most asynchronous code only runs efficiently if there is a free thread pool thread available, and if there are no thread pool threads available, then asynchronous code may be delayed.

Another part of the puzzle is that the thread pool has a limited thread injection rate. This is deliberate, so that the thread pool isn't constantly creating/destroying threads as its load varies. That would be very inefficient. Instead, a thread pool that has all of its threads busy (and still has more work to do) will only add a thread every few seconds.

The final concept to recognize is that `Lazy<T>` is [blocking when using the default `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication` behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_LazyThreadSafetyMode_ExecutionAndPublication). The way this `Lazy<T>` works is that only one thread executes the delegate (`() => InitializeContainer().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`). All other threads block, waiting for that delegate to complete.

So now, putting it all together:

- A large number of work items are placed onto the thread pool work queue (by `Task.Run`). The thread pool begins executing only as many work items as it has threads.
- Each of these work items accesses the `Container` (i.e., `Lazy<Container>.Value`), so each one of these work items blocks a thread until the initialization is complete. Only the *first* work item accessing `Container` will run the initialization code.
- The (asynchronous) initialization code attempts to make progress, but it needs a thread pool thread to be free in order to handle housekeeping when its `await`s complete. So it is also queueing very small work items to the thread pool as necessary.
- The thread pool has more work than it can handle, so it begins adding threads. Since it has a limited thread injection rate, it will only add a thread every few seconds.

The thread pool is overwhelmed with work, but it can't know *which* work items are the important ones. Most of its work items will just block on the `Lazy<T>`, which uses up another thread. The thread pool cannot know which work items are the ones from the asynchronous initialization code that will free up the other work items (and threads). So most of the threads added by the thread pool just end up blocking on other work that is having a hard time to complete since there are no thread pool threads available.

So, let's talk solutions.

IMO, the easiest solution is to remove (most of) the blocking. Allow the initialization to be asynchronous by changing the lazy type from `Lazy<Container>` to `Lazy<Task<Container>>`. The `Lazy<Task<T>>` pattern is "asynchronous lazy initialization", and it works by Lazy-initializing a *task*.

The `Lazy<T>` part of `Lazy<Task<T>>` ensures that only the first caller begins executing the asynchronous initialization code. As soon as that asynchronous code yields at an `await` ([and thus returns a `Task`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)), the `Lazy<T>` part is done. So the blocking of other threads is very brief.

Then all the work items get the same `Task<T>`, and they can all `await` it. A single `Task<T>` can be safely awaited any number of times. Once the asynchronous initialization code is complete, the `Task<T>` gets a result, and all the `await`ing work items can continue executing. Any *future* calls to the `Lazy<Task<T>>.Value` will immediately get a completed `Task<T>` which takes no time at all to `await` since it is already completed.

Once you wrap your head around `Lazy<Task<T>>`, it's pretty straightforward to use. The only awkward part is that the code for the work items now have to `await` the shared asynchronous initialization:

```
public class Do
{
  private Lazy<Task<Container>> lazyContainer;
  private Task<Container> ContainerTask => lazyContainer.Value;

  public Do()
  {
    lazyContainer = new Lazy<Task<Container>>(InitializeContainer);
  }

  public async Task<T> ReadItemAsync<T>(string id, string partitionKey)
  {
    // This is the awkward part. Until you get used to it. :)
    var container = await ContainerTask;

    var itemResponse = await container.ReadItemAsync<T>(id, new PartitionKey(partitionKey));

    return itemResponse.Resource;
  }

  // other methods are unchanged.
}
```

I have an `AsyncLazy<T>` type in [my AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx), which is essentially the same as `Lazy<Task<T>>` with a few usability enhancements.

More information on this pattern:

- [Asynchronous lazy initialization blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html).
- Recipe 14.1 "Initializing Shared Resources" in my book [Concurrency in C# Cookbook, 2nd edition](https://stephencleary.com/book/).

The `Lazy<Task<T>>` asynchronous lazy initialization pattern works great if you have a widely shared resource that may or may not need to be initialized. If you have a local resource (like a `private` member as in this example), and if you know you will *always* want it initialized, then you can make the code simpler by just using `Task<T>` instead of `Lazy<Task<T>>`:

```
public class Do
{
  private Task<Container> ContainerTask;

  public Do()
  {
    // Important semantic change:
    //   This begins initialization *immediately*.
    //   It does not wait for work items to request the container.
    ContainerTask = InitializeContainer();
  }

  public async Task<T> ReadItemAsync<T>(string id, string partitionKey)
  {
    var container = await ContainerTask;

    var itemResponse = await container.ReadItemAsync<T>(id, new PartitionKey(partitionKey));

    return itemResponse.Resource;
  }

  // other methods are unchanged.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, for the very detailed answer!